# Can I change SVG "xlink:href" of image tag just use CSS?

Tags: css, svg

My SVG pattern Shown below

```
<pattern id="img1" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="10" height="10">
    <image xlink:href="Buzz.jpg" x="0" y="0" width="10" height="10" />
</pattern>
<pattern id="img2" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="10" height="10">
    <image xlink:href="Tank-icon2.png" x="0" y="0" width="10" height="10" />
</pattern>
```

Now, I want to change xlink:href="Buzz.jpg" to xlink:href="Buzz2.jpg". Can I just do it by CSS?

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot use CSS to change HTML tag attributes.